# SpeedDial color change - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, speed-dial

I'm trying to change **SpeedDial** **color** in material-ui. But I can only change three color "default", "primary", and "secondary" using FabProps.

```
<SpeedDial
  ariaLabel="SpeedDial openIcon example"
  className={st.speedDial}
  FabProps={{
    color: "secondary",
  }}
></SpeedDial>
```

How can I change SpeedDial color using by **Hex-color**(like "#F19920")??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.

1. You can add custom classes to the component using `classes={{}}` prop.

[Here](https://material-ui.com/api/speed-dial/#css) are the classes you can pass to the component. And [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-qo7q9?file=/demo.tsx) is an example of those classes being used to change your color, on line 26 I add the className, and on line 64 I use it.

2. Another way is you can overwrite the pallet in your `theme` object, [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#official-color-tool). This way you can use `color="primary"` and it will use the color that you specified in the pallet.